# Xamarin - Android - Opening item from Navigation view?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android, navigation-drawer

Quite new to Xamarin Android. Not sure how exactly to call another view/page from the if statement below - I've seen others use fragment or case statements for this, but I'm just learning so don't want to change too much. This is the basic  Navigation Drawer Template with VS17.

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {

            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);
            Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar toolbar = FindViewById<Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar>(Resource.Id.toolbar);
            SetSupportActionBar(toolbar);

            FloatingActionButton fab = FindViewById<FloatingActionButton>(Resource.Id.fab);
            fab.Click += FabOnClick;

            DrawerLayout drawer = FindViewById<DrawerLayout>(Resource.Id.drawer_layout);
            ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer, toolbar, Resource.String.navigation_drawer_open, Resource.String.navigation_drawer_close);
            drawer.AddDrawerListener(toggle);
            toggle.SyncState();

            NavigationView navigationView = FindViewById<NavigationView>(Resource.Id.nav_view);
            navigationView.SetNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
        }
```

Below is the if statement I was refaring to - I'm trying to understand how to open another activity or view from here when selected.

```
public bool OnNavigationItemSelected(IMenuItem item)
    {

        int id = item.ItemId;

        if (id == Resource.Id.nav_support)
        {

        }

        else if (id == Resource.Id.nav_housing)
        {

        }
        else if (id == Resource.Id.nav_council)
        {

        }
        else if (id == Resource.Id.nav_education)
        {

        }
        else if (id == Resource.Id.nav_employment)
        {

        }
        else if (id == Resource.Id.nav_transport)
        {

        }
        else if (id == Resource.Id.nav_policing)
        {


        }
        else if (id == Resource.Id.nav_fire)
        {

        }
        else if (id == Resource.Id.nav_medical)
        {

        }
        DrawerLayout drawer = FindViewById<DrawerLayout>(Resource.Id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.CloseDrawer(GravityCompat.Start);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `intent` to open another activity in the another activity.
For example:

```
public class MyNavigationItemSelectedListener : Java.Lang.Object, NavigationView.IOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
{
    Context context;
    public MyNavigationItemSelectedListener(Context context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }


    bool NavigationView.IOnNavigationItemSelectedListener.OnNavigationItemSelected(IMenuItem item)
    {
        int id = item.ItemId;

        if (id == Resource.Id.nav_support)
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, typeof(SupportActivity));  //the activity you want to open
            context.StartActivity(intent);

        }
        ///Other code
        ///...
        ///...
        ///...

    }
}
```